# Two data sources seem to break things

Tags: search

I'm currently trying to get a Views search page set up, but am running into a roadblock when using 2 different data sources.
My process for creating a working search page, starting after installing Search API and disabling the default core search module:

1. I go to /admin/config/search/search-api and click Add Index.
2. In the subsequent page I give it a name (Content Index) check off Content from data sources, and choose 'Database Server' from the Server list. I click 'Save and Add Fields'.
3. In the following 'Add Fields to index' page I add Title and click Done. I set Title's Type to Fulltext and click Save changes in the subsequent screen.
4. I then go to the View tab and click Index now to index all of the data.
5. I then go to /admin/structure/views and click Add view.
6. I give my new view a name (Content Search) and in the View Settings 'Show' dropdown I select 'Index Content Index'. I check off 'Create a page' and click Save and edit.
7. In the Edit View page, I add a filter, check off 'Fulltext search' and click 'Add and configure filter criteria'.
8. I check off 'Expose this filter to...' and in Searched fields I click Content >> Title and then click Apply. Then I save the entire view.

When I view this page and test it, everything works fine. Anything I search for returns whatever piece of content has the search term as it's title. When I set this up in the same way for Field Collections, it works perfectly.

When I set the index to account for two data sources in step 2, it seems to index all of the content I want, but the search results only return the content that contains the search term and not the field collections that have that term.

Is there a setting anywhere I need to adjust to account for both data sources?